# Can I use lambda to accept two arguments in python and use it along with map

Tags: python, lambda

I want to write solve this in python a function a list of words and an integer n and returns the list of words that are longer than n i.e

```
retlist=list()
def retword(list,n):
    for i in list:
        if len(i)>=n:  
            retlist.append(i)   
return retlist
```

I can easily do this using this function but I want to solve this using map, filter, reduce and lambda expressions. Something like this

```
map(lambda list,len:list[i] if len(list[i])> len, (list,len))
```

Comment: To answer the question in your title: yes. But you just need to use filter, no map. And you need a lambda that returns True or False. You can't put `if` inside a function call. You also can't call a variable `len` if you plan to use that as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda s: len(s) >= n, list)
```

Comment: How can i pass the ``n`` here

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions will do the job you need if `a` is original list and `n` is the desired length:

```
retlist = [i for i in a if len(i) >= n]
```